# Wordpress change the language according to country

Tags: wordpress, geolocation, wpml

I am setting up a website with WordPress and WPML. Is it possible to change the language automatically according to the country? Maybe working with IP or something else.

I am looking for Plugins or a solution, which are single to configure.

I found a solution which uses the browser language. That´s not exactly what I want.

Answer (score 2):

In WPML this is only possible via [Browser language redirect](https://wpml.org/documentation/getting-started-guide/language-setup/automatic-redirect-based-on-browser-language/)
But you could use [IP2Location Redirection](https://wordpress.org/plugins/ip2location-redirection/) plugin to redirect users according their IP address.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible. I've faced with this issue earlier and made a plugin for this purpose:

[WPML automatic language with GeoIP](https://github.com/ocReaper/wpml-automatic-language-with-geoip). It

> automatically changes the load of language in WPML based on the GeoIP service

Answer (score 0):

Not possible with WPML but you should be able to do it with a plugin like [IP2Location Redirection](https://wordpress.org/plugins/ip2location-redirection/).

Comment: Thanks. I will try it very soon.